# How can I create a custom behavior for a URL scheme?

Tags: terminal, automator, url, links

I would like a specific URL scheme, `magnet:`, to run a command in Terminal.

For example:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:bKKH
```

Would execute:

```
myCommand "magnet:?xt=urn:bKKH"
```

Comment: There is no way typing e.g. `magnet:?xt=urn:bKKH` in a Terminal is gong to do anything other then `-bash: magnet:?xt=urn:bKKH: command not found` unless you actually have an executable named e.g. `magnet:?xt=urn:bKKH`.  That said, I see you have an "automator" tag set so if Automator is involved, or not, I think you need to clarify what you're asking for and in what context.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding. I won't type magnet in my terminal, I will click on a magnet link on my browser.

Comment: [This Super User post](http://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer using AppleScript:

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/127152-Launching-External-Applications-using-Custom-Protocols-under-OSX

- Create an AppleScript that uses `on open location this_URL`
- Save as Application
- Edit the Info.plist of the Application with:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>Magnet</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>magnet</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  ```